# Need some assistance converting to conjunctive normal form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been asked to convert a couple formulas to CNF. I've tried them several times but I always get stuck at the same point. They are as follows:

> $(P \to (Q \to R)) \to (P \to (R \to Q))$
>
> $ \neg(P \to (Q \to R)) \lor (P \to (R \to Q))$
>
> $ \neg (\neg P \lor (\neg Q \lor R)) \lor (\neg P \lor  (\neg R \lor Q))$
>
> $(P \land \neg(\neg Q \lor R)) \lor (\neg P \lor (\neg R \lor Q))$
>
> $(P \land (Q \land \neg R)) \lor (\neg P \lor (\neg R \lor Q))$
>
> stuck here

The second problem and my attempt at it is as follows:

> $(P \land Q) \to (\neg P \leftrightarrow Q)$
>
> $\neg(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \leftrightarrow Q)$
>
> $\neg(P \land Q) \lor ((\neg P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q))$
>
> $(\neg P \lor \neg Q) \lor ((\neg P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q))$
>
> stuck here

Can some enlighten me on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both problems, you need to use distributivity. Alternately, it may be easier to simply draw up a truth table and read the CNF by negating the DNF of the negation of the statement. I'll work out both forms and you can try them on the second.

First method: Using $(A\wedge B)\vee C\equiv(A\vee B)\wedge(A\vee C)$

$$(P\wedge (Q\wedge\neg R))\vee(\neg P\vee(\neg R\vee Q))\equiv $$$$(P\vee(\neg P\vee(\neg R\vee Q)))\wedge((Q\wedge\neg R)\vee(\neg P\vee(\neg R\vee Q)))\equiv$$
$$(P\vee\neg P\vee\neg R\vee Q)\wedge(Q\vee\neg P\vee\neg R\vee Q)\wedge(\neg R\vee\neg P\vee\neg R\vee Q)$$

I did a few steps at once between the second and third lines, but the crucial thing is to understand the trick. Moving from the first line to the second line, I used the rule stated above, setting $A\equiv P, B\equiv (Q\wedge\neg R), C\equiv (\neg P\vee(\neg R\vee Q))$. Work it out yourself, and try to 'see' why this rule makes sense in the first place.

I think the easier way to do this is using truth tables. Let the original proposition be called $\alpha$.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline P & Q & R & \alpha & \neg \alpha\\\hline
1&1&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
\end{array}
$$

Now from this table you can read off a DNF for $\alpha$ just by saying "It's true if $P\wedge Q\wedge R$, OR $P\wedge Q\wedge\neg R$ OR... so you just disjunct the conjunctions from every line where the formula is true.

Now to get CNF is a little sneakier. You take a DNF for the *negation* of $\alpha$, in this case $P\wedge \neg Q\wedge R$, and then you negate it again; obviously this is equivalent to $\alpha$ again, as $\neg\neg\alpha\equiv\alpha$. But by negating a DNF, you turn it into a CNF, because of the way negation affects $\wedge$ and $\vee$. Watch:

$$\neg(\neg\alpha)\equiv\neg(P\wedge\neg Q\wedge R)\equiv\neg P\vee Q\vee\neg R$$

And this is in CNF, where you only have one clause. Now this looks a lot simpler, which isn't always how it works, but it's definitely equivalent to the first answer we got. (Simplify that one and see why)

Now try apply these to the second problem. :)